# Linking.getInitialURL() promise resolves always null only when app is not running

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, deep-linking, android-deep-link

How I run deeplinks via adb:

```bash
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://my.site.com/my/path" com.my.app.package
```

In this AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<manifest ...>
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
   ...
  <application>
    <activity>
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:host="my.site.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/my/path"
            android:scheme="https" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

In MainActivity.java with App closed I get the deeplink correctly, but it seems to be not passed to the RN layer:

```java
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();

    System.out.println("[MainActivity][onCreate] action="+action);

    if(data != null) {
      System.out.println("[MainActivity][onCreate] data="+data.toString());
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
```

React native version: 0.66

On the React Native code:

```js
Linking.addEventListener('https', handler);
...
Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {console.log(JSON.stringify(url));}
```

the `handler` related to event fires always when app is in background or opened and I get the url correctyl.

The `Linking.getInitialURL()` resolves always **null** and the event listener never fires when app is closed.

On iOS all works fine.

| App state | iOS | Android |
| --- | --- | --- |
| opened | ✅ | ✅ |
| background | ✅ | ✅ |
| closed | ✅ | ❌ |

I need React Native handles the URL passed from the deep link when the App is closed on Android.

> If more info are needed, please ask for them and I will update this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a fresh new Intent:
for example my dynamic link is: https://myappname.link/k5uCqpw3R2Uh1E

therefor the android:scheme would be **https**

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
        </intent-filter>
        **<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>**
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

path : android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

where your intent-filter tag of BROWSABLE must be in activity of .MainActivity

example :

```
 <activity
    android:exported="true"
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="www.example.com" android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:host="www.example.com" android:scheme="https"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```